# Spring Cloud Config Client Located Server: properties not loaded

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am sure this is some kind of boot/cloud version dependency issue but I can't figure out the combination of dependencies and property values.

Config Servers starts and properties are available in browser
localhost:8888/master/ucdp-ingest
localhost:8888/master/ucdp-ingest-dev

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.14.1 2022-02-08 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.14.10.1 (build 11.0.14.1+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.14.10.1 (build 11.0.14.1+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Therefore according to [2021-0-3 Availability](https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/27/spring-cloud-2021-0-3-is-available-compatible-with-spring-boot-2-7-0) and the java version we use, went with

- Spring Boot: 2.7.6
- Spring Cloud: 2021.0.3

Client pom

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <aws-sdk.version>1.12.368</aws-sdk.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.12.0</commons-lang3.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.8</jacoco.version>
        <jasypt-spring-boot.version>3.0.5</jasypt-spring-boot.version>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring-cloud-stream-kinesis-binder.version>2.2.0</spring-cloud-stream-kinesis-binder.version>
        <springdoc-openapi-ui.version>1.6.14</springdoc-openapi-ui.version>
        <swagger-maven-plugin.version>2.1.6</swagger-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring cloud -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Note no "spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap" per documentation.
Interestingly "spring.profiles.active" shows deprecated.
However, according to [Spring 2.4 docs](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4) it should be spring.config.activate.on-profile. This doesn't resolve as system property.

```
  -Dspring.config.activate.on-profile=dev
2022-12-23 15:28:51.358  INFO 36316 --- [           main] c.b.u.ucdp.ingest.UcdpIngestApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
```

Client: application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: ucdp-ingest
  cloud:
    config:
      name: ${spring.application.name}
      uri: http://localhost:8888
      username: ----------
      password: ---------
      request-connect-timeout: 3000
      request-read-timeout: 3000
      retry:
        initial-interval: 1000
        max-attempts: 6
      label: master
      fail-fast: true
  config:
    import: "configserver:"

server:
  port: 8300
  servlet:
    context-path: /${spring.application.name}

  # Actuator
  management:
    #opt-in use enabled-by-default: false then enable what you want. default = true
    enabled-by-default: true
    server:
      port: ${server.port}
    endpoints:
      web:
        base-path: ${server.servlet.context-path}
        exposure:
          include: "*"
    endpoint:
      env:
        enabled: true
      health:
        show-details: always
        enabled: true
      info:
        enabled: true
#      shutdown:
#        enabled: true

#OpenAPI
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /docs/api-docs
    version: openapi_3_1
  swagger-ui:
    path: /docs/swagger-ui
  paths-to-match: /**
```

REMOTE application-ucdp-ingest.yml

```
app:
  ucdp:
    url: https://ucdpapi.pcr.uu.se/api
    connect-timeout-millis: 2000
    read-timeout-seconds: 2000
  ged:
    job:
      enabled: true
      cron: "20 49 11 * * ?"
    #Max page size is 1000
    pageSize: 1000
    uri: /gedevents/21.1
```

REMOTE application-ucdp-ingest-dev.yml
contains mongo and aws connection properties. Mongo also failed to connect because properties were not loaded remotely.

LOGS: Note I am passing profile as system property.

```
+ /c/sfw/java/jdk11.0.14_10/bin/java -Dspring.config.activate.on-profile=dev -Dlogging.config=/c/projects/ucdp-ingest/ucdp-ingest-app/config/logback.xml -jar /c/projects/ucdp-ingest/ucdp-ingest-app/target/ucdp-ingest-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar


2022-12-23 15:30:50.081  INFO 20496 --- [           main] c.b.u.ucdp.ingest.UcdpIngestApplication  : Starting UcdpIngestApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.14.1 on BRANDA-BSTAQ-PC with PID 20496 (C:\projects\ucdp-ingest\ucdp-ingest-app\target\ucdp-ingest-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by BruceRandall in C:\projects\ucdp-ingest\ucdp-ingest-app)
2022-12-23 15:30:50.086  INFO 20496 --- [           main] c.b.u.ucdp.ingest.UcdpIngestApplication  : The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
2022-12-23 15:30:50.136  INFO 20496 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2022-12-23 15:30:50.137  INFO 20496 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Located environment: name=ucdp-ingest, profiles=[dev], label=master, version=7102644c36175df62e3a3952793021cdf730583a, state=null
2022-12-23 15:30:51.495  INFO 20496 --- [           main] ptablePropertiesBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Post-processing PropertySource instances
2022-12-23 15:30:51.496  INFO 20496 --- [           main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Skipping PropertySource configurationProperties [class org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertySource
2022-12-23 15:30:51.498  INFO 20496 --- [           main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Skipping PropertySource servletConfigInitParams [class org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource$StubPropertySource
2022-12-23 15:30:51.498  INFO 20496 --- [           main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Skipping PropertySource servletContextInitParams [class org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource$StubPropertySource
2022-12-23 15:30:51.499  INFO 20496 --- [           main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource systemProperties [org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2022-12-23 15:30:51.499  INFO 20496 --- [           main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource systemEnvironment [org.springframework.boot.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySourceEnvironmentPostProcessor$OriginAwareSystemEnvironmentPropertySource] to EncryptableSystemEnvironmentPropertySourceWrapper
2022-12-23 15:30:51.500  INFO 20496 --- [           main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource random [org.springframework.boot.env.RandomValuePropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
2022-12-23 15:30:51.500  INFO 20496 --- [           main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource cachedrandom [org.springframework.cloud.util.random.CachedRandomPropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
2022-12-23 15:30:51.500  INFO 20496 --- [           main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource springCloudClientHostInfo [org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2022-12-23 15:30:51.500  INFO 20496 --- [           main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource configClient [org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2022-12-23 15:30:51.500  INFO 20496 --- [           main] c.u.j.EncryptablePropertySourceConverter : Converting PropertySource Config resource 'file [config\application.yml]' via location 'optional:file:./config/' [org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedMapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper

2022-12-23 15:30:51.664  INFO 20496 --- [           main] c.u.j.filter.DefaultLazyPropertyFilter   : Property Filter custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyFilter'. Initializing Default Property Filter
2022-12-23 15:30:51.673  INFO 20496 --- [           main] c.u.j.r.DefaultLazyPropertyResolver      : Property Resolver custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyResolver'. Initializing Default Property Resolver
2022-12-23 15:30:51.675  INFO 20496 --- [           main] c.u.j.d.DefaultLazyPropertyDetector      : Property Detector custom Bean not found with name 'encryptablePropertyDetector'. Initializing Default Property Detector
2022-12-23 15:30:52.246  INFO 20496 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8300 (http)
2022-12-23 15:30:52.256  INFO 20496 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-12-23 15:30:52.256  INFO 20496 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.69]
2022-12-23 15:30:52.351  INFO 20496 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/ucdp-ingest]   : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-12-23 15:30:52.351  INFO 20496 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2212 ms

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gedJob' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/projects/ucdp-ingest/ucdp-ingest-app/target/ucdp-ingest-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/bar/udl/ucdp/ingest/service/impl/GedJob.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'executeJob': 
Could not resolve placeholder 'app.ged.job.cron' in value "${app.ged.job.cron}"
```

```
ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Located environment: name=ucdp-ingest, profiles=[dev], label=master, version=7102644c36175df62e3a3952793021cdf730583a, state=null
Could not resolve placeholder 'app.ged.job.cron' in value "${app.ged.job.cron}"
```

Unfortunately, [ConfigServerConfigDataLoader](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/main/spring-cloud-config-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/client/ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.java) doesn't give you a complete URL

Configuration Server Endpoint
http://localhost:8888/master/ucdp-ingest

```
{
  "name": "master",
  "profiles": [
    "ucdp-ingest"
  ],
  "label": null,
  "version": "155b907870c49c194dee1f1b6d94be768ce043ec",
  "state": null,
  "propertySources": [
    {
      "name": "C:\\\\projects\\\\udl-app-config/file:C:\\Users\\BRUCER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\config-repo-1334124828626900950\\application-ucdp-ingest.yml",
      "source": {
        "app.ucdp.url": "https://ucdpapi.pcr.uu.se/api",
        "app.ucdp.connect-timeout-millis": 2000,
        "app.ucdp.read-timeout-seconds": 2000,
        "app.ged.job.enabled": true,
        "app.ged.job.cron": "20 49 11 * * ?",
        "app.ged.pageSize": 1000,
        "app.ged.uri": "/gedevents/21.1",
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverted back to boot 2.4.3, cloud 2020.0.3 but will be working back up to boot 2.7.6 cloud 2021.0.3.

The main issue was incorrectly interpreting the specification for the naming convention for property files. I noticed when querying the configuration server the name was the branch and the profile was the application name. Hence the reason I could only pull properties with localhost:8888/master/app-name-profile

Once I removed application from my file names in the git repository to ${spring.application.name}-profile I was able to query the server correctly and
the client was able to connect and load properties.

My last issue is I can't pass the profile in as a system property -Dspring.profiles.active=dev resolves to default when the bean access the Config Server.